# Can't I call a stored procedure from Entity Framework inside a transaction scope?

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, transactionscope

I have a method that uses Entity Framework to do some changes/inserts in different entities, all this inside a single transaction scope. These changes works very well.

My problem has began when I needed to use a stored procedure in the middle of these operations. The procedure does only an insert in one table, and has no explicit declaration of transactions. I've tried declaring a transaction and commiting there also, but the problem was the same.

Can't I call a stored procedure from Entity Framework (EF1) inside a transaction scope?

This exception is thrown only after transaction.Complete(), when the using block is closed.

```
The transaction has aborted.

   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromotedAborted.PromotedTransactionOutcome(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromotedEnded.EndCommit(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.CommittableTransaction.Commit()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.InternalDispose()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.Dispose()
```

Inner exception:

```
The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction.

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDelegatedTransaction.SinglePhaseCommit(SinglePhaseEnlistment enlistment)
```

**UPDATE: Started a bounty**

Today I'm not doing this procedure call through Entity Framework anymore. I'm calling the procedure through ADO.net, this was my workaround. But the problem continues, I should need make some calls in the near future, maybe inside a transaction scope.

Comment: By now, I'm calling the stored procedure from plain old ado.net, using another connection string to the same database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bug with a hotifx? [KB 936983](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936983)

Answer (score 19):

I Finally found a solution...it seems EF expects the stored proc (imported function) to return a value.
so call .FirstOrDefault() on the function when it returns.

Comment: This helped me as well. It worked fine after returning the value (even if I didn't use it at all)

Comment: This fixed the problem we were hitting here also. How is this not an EF bug?

Comment: Yup, that's pretty much it. You have to evaluate the result. More info: https://christianarg.wordpress.com/2010/12/04/entity-framework-4-execute-a-writing-stored-procedure-inside-a-transactionscope/